# Linux Execute a normal process from a kernel thread?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have a simple question, can i execute a normal process from kernel thread?

We have one redhat server wich running a kernel thread named [jssu] provided by oracle wich is parent of normal process

Thanks

Comment: There is at least one commonly used way to spawn a user-mode process from the kernel: the [usermode helper API](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-user-space-apps/). Other ways may also exist.

Comment: I mean even if it is a duplicate; I want to provide a working poc (hopefully working in the sense of for those who need it) sometimes one don't have time to look trough pages (not saying it's bad) but for those who just are in a hurry and will read later;   or just wants a poc - (note - it is my github profile; I am only submitting this for the simple reason to those who need it https://github.com/loneicewolf/EXEC_LKM ) (it is based on the http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-user-space-apps/ link Eugene provided)

Comment: The best thing (in my opinion) is to  (as @Eugene states ) read about it in the link Eugene provided;